The createRecord API won't accept recordTypeId as a parameter. How can I provide it?
I have developed a simple but custom LWC that acts as my client's "Create a Support Case" form. I've collected all the necessary information to create a Case record, however, I am unable to provide the recordTypeId to specify that the createRecord operation should create a specific type of Case object. It seems to be defaulting to the "Standard Case" type.
Here's my code:
//create case button
handleClick() {
  
    const fields = {};

    fields['subject'] = this.subject;
    fields['description'] = this.description;
         
    const recordInput = {
      apiName: 'Case',
      recordTypeId: '{myRecordTypeId}'
      fields: fields
    };
        
    createRecord(recordInput).then((record) => {
      console.log(record);
    });
  }

In the console, I see that my record is "standard" instead of the recordTypeId I am providing in the recordInput object.
Here is the documentation I've been following.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-create-record.html

The way that you handle this is by providing the recordTypeId as a "field". So instead of the recordInput being constructed like this with recordTypeId provided next to apiName:
const fields = {};

    fields['Subject'] = this.subject;
    fields['Description'] = this.description;

    const recordInput = {
      apiName: 'Case',
      recordTypeId: '{myRecordTypeId}'
      fields: fields
    };

what you actually want is this:
const fields = {};

    fields['subject'] = this.subject;
    fields['description'] = this.description;
    fields['RecordTypeId'] = '{myRecordTypeId}'

    const recordInput = {
      apiName: 'Case',
      fields: fields
    };

Notice a very important detail that the field name is capitalized !!!
